# RAILS 4: problems with 'delete' button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested, nested-resources

I have a nested resource, comments like so....

```
resources :microposts do

   member do
     get :upvote, :undo_upvote
   end

   member do
     get :follow, :unfollow
   end

   resources :responses do
     member do
       get :upvote, :undo_upvote
     end
     resources :comments
  end
end
```

I have a delete button on the comments index page....

```
 <div class = "Comment" id="comment-<%= comment.id %>">
     <%= link_to comment_avatar_for(comment.user), comment.user %>
     <span class="Commentator">
       <%= comment.user.full_name %>
     </span>
     <span class="content">
       <%= comment.body %>
     </span>
     <span class="timestamp">
     Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago.
     </span>
     <span class="timestamp">
       <% if current_user?(comment.user) %>
       <%= link_to "delete", comment, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "You sure?" }, :class => "btn btn-default btn-xs delete" %>
      <% end %>
     </span>
</div>
```

And I am getting this error when I load the page

```
 undefined method `comment_path' for #<#  <Class:0x007f8936876e70>:0x007f8931857020>
```

I am uncertain why this isn't working - after all I have the correct instance of 'comment'. If someone could just point me in the right direction I would be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails makes assumptions.

Because you have an instance of `Comment` it assumes you're going to be using `comment_path`, but you don't have that as per your routes so you need to set the correct path:

```
<%= link_to "delete", micropost_response_comment_path(@micropost, @response, comment), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "You sure?" }, :class => "btn btn-default btn-xs delete" %>
```

I might have the path wrong, but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: OP should determine if the `@micropost` and `@response` resources are needed if one wants to delete a `comment`.

Comment: Works...although I am interested in Magnuss's comment. I assume he means, simply specific the route.

Comment: Yes, a specific route. Since you may not care about the parent resources to delete a comment. Thus having something like:  `<%= link_to "delete", comment_path(comment)...`. But all in all, there's nothing more to it than a shorter path.